# What is the probability that a customer will buy at least one article from a given family?

Tags: probability

Each grocery store receipt details all articles bought and in what quantity. Grouping different articles based on their general purpose gives us multiple "article families". Examples of these article families could be "Baking", where baking articles are integrated, or "Drinks", where all drink articles are integrated.

Analysing a mass amount (let's say 100.000) of receipts can help us understand customer behaviour and what is the general probability that a single article is purchased.

Assuming that from the 100.000 analyzed receipts, 10.000 had at least one Baking article, the probability that a random customer will buy an item from this family is pBaking = 10.000/100.000 = 10%.

If pDrinks = 15% , how do I calculate the probability that a random customer will buy at least one item from Baking OR Drinks?

Comment: Without further information, all that can be said is that it can be anything between $15$% and $25$%

Comment: Expanding on the comment of @trueblueanil, the problem analogizes to the set theory problem of enumerating the number of elements in a set.  For any set $~E~$ with a finite number of elements, let $~|E|~$ denote the number of elements in the set $~E.~$  Then, you have the general formula that $~|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|.~$  By analogy, the terms $~|A|~$ and $~|B|~$ are known, and you want to calculate $~|A \cap B|.~$  As you can see from the formula, to perform the computation, you also need to know $~|A \cup B|.$

Comment: pBaking + pDrinks is obviously 25%, because it's the sum of the two given numbers. What I think your are trying to ask is either a) the probability that someone buys both a drink **and** a baking article, or b) the probability that somone buys a drink **or** a baking article (including buying both).  Can you clarify what exactly you mean?

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as pBaking + pDrinks.
If I have 20 different article families and 10 of them each have at least 10% probability of being bought, it doesn't mean that a customer will have over 100% of probability of buying at least one article from any of those families.
After studying a little more, I think the answer is:
P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)
where
P(A and B) = P(A) x P(B)
Using these equations we have:
p(Baking or Drinks)= 0,10 + 0,15 - 0,10 x 0,15 = 23,5%

Is this wrong?

Comment: Another interesting part is that when I want to calculate the probability for more than 2 article families, it's not enough to sum all of them and then subtract their product. Instead, I think it's necessary to split it into several equations which "feed" each other.
It's hard for me to explain without showing you an excel table, because I don't know enough math to put it into an equation. Is it possible to post tables or pictures here, so that I can demonstrate a real case from a real store?

Comment: Nobody - not even Ingix - claimed what you were after was the sum of pBaking  and pDrinks. true blue anil and user2661923 pointed out exactly the problem you did (but didn't offer your incorrect solution). Ingix is pointing out that you didn't ask for $P(A\text{ or }B)$ in your question, nor did you ask for $P(A\text{ and }B)$. You asked for $P(A) + P(B)$, which actually is just the sum of the two numbers. That is, you didn't ask the question you intended to ask. And the question you did ask is trivial. The point was to get you to clarify your question (by editing it, not just in comments).

Comment: You are correct that $$P(A\text{ or }B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\text{ and }B)$$ But you are wrong that $P(A\text{ and }B) = P(A)P(B)$. That is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent. That is, if people who buy baking goods are just as likely to buy drinks as those who do not buy baking goods. There is no a priori reason this has to be true. Maybe the bakers find it a thirsty job, and so are more likely to buy drinks.

Comment: You're right, I didn't phrase my question correctly. Although trivial to you, this is a question which I find challenging and interesting. Part of the problem is defining it properly, which I evidently couldn't do. I will edit my question to clarify. Thank you for the heads-up!